# Deleting .po and .mo files from WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, po, mo

I have several themes that contain .mo and .po files for translations.

The only reference to these files in the code is similar to this:

```
load_theme_textdomain('ThemeName',$template_dir.'/lang');
```

Would it be safe to delete the `lang` directory from these themes if I don't need to translate the theme for any reason?  There are language files for English (en_US), but it doesn't look like they are actually used by the themes since the text is directly in the PHP files...

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just not really sure how these files work with WordPress.

Comment: They are the base files to do replacements with something like PO Edit. You don't need them if you aren't using them. I would say, if you are using themes you bought, they will just reappear on updating :)

Comment: Yea I'm not really worried about updates.  The customer just doesn't understand why there's a "lang" folder with different translations they don't need.  Their worried about the files using space on their hosting account and I can't seem to get them to understand how little 55.3 KB is :)

Comment: Well it's also good if there is English text that they would like changed. For instance, we have a client that I needed to change "products" on their WooCommerce build to be "brochures" everywhere. It was about a 3 minutes deal with the language file and I don't need to worry too much about ever updating it. But with a theme the customization needed is probably more in your end than theirs (for better user readability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you will see commands like

```
__('Some text','Themename');
_e('Some text','Themename');
```

If you set WP_LANG to "de_DE" in case you are in Germany, your WordPress installation will look for the file Themename-de_DE.mo in the /lang folder to find a translation.

If you remove the files/folder I would also remove the `load_theme_textdomain('ThemeName',$template_dir.'/lang');` command. The files can all be removed but as mentioned in the comments, they will return on update.

Answer (score 0):

The text is in fact in the PHP files, but it should appear in special functions like `_e()` for example: these functions translates the given strings thanks to the `*.mo` files. For example, if you configured your WordPress installation to use it in French, WordPress will search for french `*.mo` files and will use them if they exist (if it is not the case, it does not translate anything).

If you don't need any translation, you can in fact remove the `lang` directory without any problem.